# ESP32 missing names during BLE scan

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm running a sample code from ESP32 examples and I'm scanning available BLE devices. I can see device MAC address etc. But for few devices I can't see their names.
I am using ESP-WROOM-32 with hardware support checked out directly from their github.
When I use LightBlue app for discovery of BLE Devices I can see names for more devices than ESP can. What can I change to see the names correctly? OR Can how can I parse device name from the data I'm receiving?

This callback code

```
class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
    void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
      Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());
      Serial.print(" RSSI: ");
      Serial.println(advertisedDevice.getRSSI());
    }
};
```

produces this output:

```
Advertised Device: Name: , Address: 1d:0c:c7:3a:fb:c6, manufacturer data: 4c0009060378c0a81f12, payload: 1073609632 
 RSSI: -75
```

Comment: isnt it possible they dont have names

Comment: I get exactly the same problem. Same empty string when trying advertisedDevice.getName().c_str().

The beacons definitely have a name.

Comment: anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

A BLE peripheral can advertise its name using either a 'long name' or a 'short name' record in either an 'advertising' or a 'scan response' packet. So each peripheral uses one of the four possible combinations.

If you're developing code for a central device using the **[ESP32 BLE Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/esp32-ble-arduino/)** library, three potential issues may arise:

#### 1. This library doesn't support "short name" records

It means that any peripheral that advertises its name through a "short name" record will appear with an empty name.

Until this is fixed by the team (you can follow up with the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/871)), you can easily fix it yourself in your local library. Locate the file `BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp` and add `case ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_SHORT:` before line 296.

The initial code is:

```cpp
            switch(ad_type) {
                case ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_CMPL: {   // Adv Data Type: 0x09
                    setName(std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(payload), length));
                    break;
                } // ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_CMPL
```

and should become:

```cpp
            switch(ad_type) {
                case ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_SHORT: 
                case ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_CMPL: {   // Adv Data Type: 0x09
                    setName(std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(payload), length));
                    break;
                } // ESP_BLE_AD_TYPE_NAME_CMPL
```

#### 2. You forgot to use setActiveScan(true)

`BLEDevice::getScan()->setActiveScan(true)` tells the library to ask peripherals for "scan response" packets. If you don't call this function, any peripheral that advertises its name through a "scan response" packet will appear with an empty name.

#### 3. You are using the default scan interval and window

In this library, the default scan interval and window are both of 10ms. It seems this is too small to allow for asking for (or receiving) "scan response" packets. Use at least:

```cpp
BLEDevice::getScan()->setInterval(40);
BLEDevice::getScan()->setWindow(40);
```

Hope this helps.